# React Native Could Not Install

Tags: android, node.js, react-native

I am attempting to run the React Native sample on Android, located: https://github.com/brentvatne/react-native-scrollable-tab-view

Following the steps:

1. cd ...\react-native-scrollable-tab-view-master\examples\FacebookTabsExample
2. npm install ---fails

The error on this step is:

```
C:\Users\KJA\ReactNativeProjects\FacebookTabsExample>npm install
npm ERR! addLocal Could not install C:\Users\KJA
npm ERR! Windows_NT 6.1.7601
npm ERR! argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\
node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install"
npm ERR! node v5.7.0
npm ERR! npm  v3.6.0
npm ERR! code EISDIR
npm ERR! errno -4068
npm ERR! syscall read

npm ERR! eisdir EISDIR: illegal operation on a directory, read
npm ERR! eisdir This is most likely not a problem with npm itself
npm ERR! eisdir and is related to npm not being able to find a package.json in
npm ERR! eisdir a package you are trying to install.

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\KJA\ReactNativeProjects\FacebookTabsExample\npm-debug.log
```

I cannot locate why this is the case? How can this be alleviated?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have installed the following modules globally first before trying to use this module

react

```
npm install react -g
```

react-native

```
npm install react-native -g
```

Then try and run the command again.

Comment: Running as administrator did not work, it yielded the same error

Comment: Can you confirm the version of react-native that you have installed? Is it installed globally? This module requires version >=0.20.0

Comment: This is the latest version I just downloaded it 4 days ago, how can I tell if it was not installed globally?

Comment: run the following command to check if react-native is installed globally "npm list -g react-native"

Comment: How can it be installed globally?

Comment: Is this simply run anywhere?

Comment: Yes the -g parameter tells npm to install it in the global npm modules folder.

Comment: Also if you get any node-gyp errors. Check out this article for the fix https://www.robertkehoe.com/2015/03/fix-node-gyp-rebuild-error-on-windows/

Comment: What else do you need to ensure that this can be fixed? What additional error messages are there?